# Print multiple pages for different scroll positions via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML page that is an output of some program.
The program is used a lot to produce evidence and it will be helpful to export this evidence to a PDF.

The HTML is split into two columns.
I need to print (to PDF) multiple pages such that each page shows the two columns where different parts of the columns are aligned.

I rely on the browser ability to print to PDF instead of to the printer.
I tried to use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) but it does not support `<pre>` tags properly which are prevalent in my text.

The document is a given HTML with two `<div>`s side by side with a scrollbar.

I already have the code that successfully aligns the two columns in the required positions, and a button that prints it using `window.print()`. It looks something like this:

```js
function align(loc) {
  $('#1').scrollTop($("#mark0"+loc).offset().top);
  $('#2').scrollTop($("#mark1"+loc).offset().top);
}

function print() {
  window.print();
}

// All locations are known in advance
function printAll() {
  for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    align(i);
    print();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=0 style='left:0; overflow:scroll; height:100%; width:50%'>
    A lot of text...
    <span id='mark01' />
    A lot of text...
    <span id='mark02' />
    A lot of text...
    <span id='mark03' />
    A lot of text...
</div>

<div id=1 style='right:0; overflow:scroll; height:100%; width:50%'>
    <pre>
        Some text.
        <b>
            A lot of text...
            <span id='mark11' />
            Some text.
        </b>
        Some text.
        <b>
            A lot of text...
        </b>
        <span id='mark12' />
        A lot of text...
        <span id='mark13' />
        <b>
            A lot of text...
        </b>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Currently, I have to align the columns using the script (user choose one of the alignments), then print to PDF (user clicks on the print button), then align to a different position, then print again, and so forth.

Is there a way to automatize this process?
I want to create a javascript script that will call `align()`, then `print()` multiple times and it will be printed in a single PDF.

The `printAll()` example obviously does not work.

Comment: @mplungjan I do save as a PDF. But I still have to do it one by one.

Comment: Why not SERVE a PDF from the server instead?

Comment: @mplungjan This is not a server application. There is no backend there.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? If you can render one page you can render two?

Comment: I have to render them one by one manually. I would like to print all the pages in one click into a single PDF.

Comment: Likely lack of code.

Comment: That is your opinion. Most SO readers want to see [mcve]

Comment: I've added some code example.

Comment: How does window.print create pdf if this is client only? I thought you used pdf.js

Comment: No. I rely on the browser ability to print to PDF instead of the printer. It is kind of the default in chrome.

Comment: That is important and missing information. Just use a js pdf writer and create all the pages in one go

Comment: @mplungjan jsPDF does not support `<pre>` tags. I have a lot of them in my text.

Comment: In what manner no support ? Did you try a mono space font?

Comment: It shows everything in one line. It stated in their documentation that it will not support it.

Answer (score 1):

Using JS, I'd construct a new section laid out for print, then move the content into it.

The goal would be to produce reasonable DOM, like this:

```
<div id="printzone">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="col"> col1 section1 </div>
        <div class="col"> col2 section1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="col"> col1 section2 </div>
        <div class="col"> col2 section2 </div>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

The first part is straightforward, but it seems obvious that the original DOM is not well-suited to the second task. You'll probably have to work with the raw source to accomplish the second step.

Perhaps something like:

```
// grab source
var col1Source = $('#0').innerHTML;
// treat '<span id="mark##" />' as a delimiter -- BOOM!
var col1Sections = col1Source.split(/<span id='mark\d+'[^>]+>/);
// do same for col2

for(var i = 0,
    iMax = Math.max(col1Sections.length, col2Sections.length);
    i < iMax;
    i++
) {
    var newPage = $('<div class="page">');
    newPage.append('<div class="col">' + col1Sections[i] + '</div>');
    newPage.append('<div class="col">' + col2Sections[i] + '</div>');
    $('#printzone').append(newPage);
}
```

Once you've finished constructing the print zone, open up your dev tools and (1) delete the original `#0` and `#1` DOM nodes, then (2) play with CSS until the print layout is satisfactory.

Comment: I have added a code example. I hope it helps.
There are only two `div`s. The alignment only changes the scrollbar location in both of them.

Comment: I considered your approach before. By duplicate the entire document a few time and put them one after another with forced page break via CSS. However, I wondered if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Nobody said anything about duplicating anything. Just wrap each pair of columns in `<div class="page">` and then write `.page { page-break-before: always; }` or somesuch. If you're good with CSS, you can probably skip the JS and handle it with `:nth-of-type` selectors.

Comment: There is only one pair of columns. The difference between the print layout is the scrollbar position.

Comment: I think I get the problem now that your post includes the page markup. You have two giant columns, and you want to vertically align them at several arbitrary points. Unless the DOM gives you hooks at the relevant places, you're boned. Copy the content into a layout app and get it over with. Sorry, friend. :(

Comment: I know the positions and successfully scroll to the correct position. The positions are marked so that is not a problem. The problem is printing a few different scroll positions in to a single PDF.

Comment: Thanks. One problem with your suggestion is that the "delimiter" might be in a nested `<span/>` and we could not just split it. I'll add it to the example.

Comment: If the document isn't structured in a way that facilitates your task, you'll have to do some pre-processing to eliminate hurdles. I don't know what else to tell you. Perhaps the lesson is just that **document outlines matter.** If this is a one-off task, just roll with it. But if you're trying to create a bookmarklet that will automagically convert tag soup that's barely fit for the web into a slick-looking print version its authors clearly didn't imagine, best of luck. I have tired of being drip-fed important details that should've been in the OP, and am tapping out. Happy coding, friend. :)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help.